# Exception on importing Blob image into ms Access report

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oracle11g, report

In an Access 2013 Report I connect to an Oracle DB View via a Linked Table. One View field is of type BLOB and holds images that have been previously stored there.

In my Access Report the linked table has a field (named BILD_INHALT) of type "OLE Object" that maps to the BLOB field in Oracle DB.

In the report view, I created an "Image" field (named MST_Image) has to load the image and it is initialized in the following way:

```
If Len(RS![BILD_INHALT]) > 0 Then
   Me.MST_Image.PictureData = RS![BILD_INHALT]
End If
```

At run time I get the following exception when I initialize MST_Image.PictureData with the content coming from Oracle.

[image]

I check on internet about further documentation about this (very old) topic, but I could not find anything about this specific issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is somewhat self-explanatory: an image control in Microsoft Access can be either bound to a file location, or can be set to a `.dib` image ([device independent bitmap format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183562%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), one of the more obscure image formats).

Working around it, though, is not that easy.

You can work around that limitation in several ways:

1. Use an ActiveX control that supports multiple image formats (there are multiple to be found)
2. Save the image to disk in a temporary folder, and set the images control source to its location
3. Use a web browser control, and use the HTML `<img />`  tag to display your image, using an [embedded BASE64 image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images)

Here is the example code for approach 3:

First, we need to be able to convert the binary code contained in the OLE object to BASE64:

```vb
Public Function ToBase64(Bytes As Variant) As String
    Dim XMLElement As Object
    Set XMLElement = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0").createElement("tmp")
    XMLElement.DataType = "bin.base64"
    XMLElement.nodeTypedValue = Bytes
    ToBase64 = Replace(XMLElement.Text, vbLf, "")
End Function
```

Then, we can use a web browser control, and insert a web page with the BASE64-encoded image into it:

```vb
Public Sub InsertImageInControl()
    Dim wb As Object
    Set wb = MyWebbrowserControl.Object
    With wb
        .Navigate2 "about:blank"
        Do Until .ReadyState = 4 '=READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            'This is a somewhat inefficient way to wait, but loading a blank page should only take a couple of milliseconds
            DoEvents
        Loop
        .Document.Open
        .Document.Write "<!DOCTYPE html><HTML><HEAD><TITLE>A</TITLE></HEAD><BODY scroll=""no"" style=""margin: 0px; padding: 0px;"">"
        .Document.Write "<img alt="""" style=""width:100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;"" src=""data:image/jpg;base64,"
        .Document.Write ToBase64(MyOLEObject.Value)
        .Document.Write """ />"
        .Document.Write "</BODY></HTML>"
        .Document.Close
    End With
End Sub
```

Where `MyWebbrowserControl` is the name of your webbrowser control, `image/jpg` is your image type, and `MyOLEObject` is your OLE object.

Tips:

- Don't use the WebBrowser ActiveX control, but use the one that comes with Access. Else, you will get an outdated version of Internet Explorer with a 3d border that can't be removed.
- Set the control source for the web browser control to `="about:blank"` to initialize it as a blank page

Comment: Many thanks Erik for the answer. The Access report has been written in VB.net by a colleague of mine and the Oracle DB source (where the images are stored as BLOBS) is under the client's control. As I have only 
 limited time to solve the issues, I will  try with your 2nd suggestion.

Comment: @Francesco As said, I do have example VBA code for the third solution, and while it may not be short, it should require little to no modification. The 2nd solution, however, is fine too.  I recommend reading [Chip Pearsons working with temporary folders and files in VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WorkingWithTempFilesAndFolders.htm) if you go for that.

Comment: I would be grateful if it would be possible to see your VBA example code, do you have it published on a blog or can you tell me how to get it? Thanks again

Comment: I've added the example here, you can review it and ask questions if you wish. Note that Internet Explorer tends to ignore the `data:image/jpg` image type, so if the image type is not constant, it tends to work fine too.

Comment: Can I use "MyWebbrowserControl.Object" directly instead of my Image Control? The image would be just a portion of the whole Report (more or less a Logo), therefore should fit inside the report instead of being an independent page.

Comment: Yes, just replace your image control with a web browser control. The web browser control will only display the image. Note that it does allow right clicking it, viewing the web page source code, and saving the image. You can add some javascript to prevent this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156983/discussion-between-francesco-and-erik-von-asmuth).