# Microsoft ACCESS doesn´t show photo in form

Tags: ms-access, hyperlink, photo

I´m creating a form that displays the info of all of the employees, including their photo.

When in design view, I've tried using an image control and defining in its control source. 
[image: See image control in form + property sheet]

However, when I change to form view and navigate the employees records, their photo isn´t shown.

I've tried changing the field (where the photos are stored) data type to text, instead of hyperlink (as shown in this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5ZOOMrDjtU ) but the photos still do not appear.

The photos are stored as hyperlinks, that show the file path, and if i'm in datasheet view of the table, I can click on the employees photo hyperlink and it opens their photo.

Also, in access options, I have this picture property storage format selected: [image: see the option selected] and the images are jpg files.

Does someone know how I can solve this issue? What could I have done wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: A true hyperlink in Access is made of 3 parts separated by # character. This won't work in Image control. Did you simply convert the hyperlink field to a text type or did you also re-enter the data as a full path string? Image control with ControlSource set to field with file path works for me.

Comment: I've deleted the data from the photos, changed the data type to text and re-entered the data. Deleted and added a new image control to the form and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: More info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50207997/access-form-abc-picture-xyz-jpg-makes-listbox-textboxes-blink-once/50269085#50269085

Comment: @June7 Consider adding that as an answer. It's certainly distinct from that linked question, and it's a valid answer to this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A true hyperlink in Access is made of 3 parts separated by # character.
`display text # file name # any reference within the file`
More info http://allenbrowne.com/casu-09.html

The hyperlink structure won't work in Image control ControlSource property and can't simply convert the hyperlink field to a text type as the resulting string will not be a valid file path. Either manually enter correct image file path or use string manipulation code to extract file path part from the hyperlink field and save to a text field (x represents fieldname):
`Mid(Left(x,InStrRev(x,"#")-1),Instr(x,"#")+1)`

On second thought, that expression could be in the ControlSource property so the hyperlink field could be retained as is and a text field not needed.

More info on expressions in ControlSource property: [Access Form: `abc.Picture="xyz.jpg"` makes listbox & textboxes "blink" once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50207997/access-form-abc-picture-xyz-jpg-makes-listbox-textboxes-blink-once/50269085#50269085)